# the word "slant" as a way of expressing personal views

Tags: word-choice, grammar

In writing, I mainly use such words as *outlook*, *perspective*, *standpoint*, or *viewpoint* to express my personal opinion or an opinion of someone else. Examples presented below:

> 1. The author's **outlook/standpoint** on economy does not comply with the mainstream view.
> 2. From my **perspective/viewpoint** the passage seems irrelevant.

Is it possible to apply the word **slant** in similar contexts?

Are there any other words which I could use?

Comment: 'Slant' is a word which I would use with great care, as it carries strong connotations of bias.

Comment: ' I think my 9-year-old grandson is the greatest footballer of his generation and will play for England one day!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely fine to use 'slant' in this way, though more often used to describe the views of a third party, not usually yourself.

Other words-

Their *views* on...
My *take* on...
Your *stance* on...
His *position* on...
Her *opinion* on...